# How to create Model from schema with Mongoose? Uncaught TypeError: User.create is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run the code from J. Wexler's book. The book is available at
[GitHub](https://github.com/JonathanWexler/get-programming-with-nodejs).

Now, I am working on  18_1,chapter 4.

I have followed all the steps in book to create `User` in REPL.

```
const User = require
("./models/user")
```

user.js

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  { Schema } = mongoose,
  userSchema = new Schema(
    {
      name: {
        first: {
          type: String,
          trim: true
        },
        last: {
          type: String,
          trim: true
        }
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
      },
      zipCode: {
        type: Number,
        min: [1000, "Zip code too short"],
        max: 99999
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      courses: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Course" }],
      subscribedAccount: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Subscriber"
      }
    },
    {
      timestamps: true
    }
  );

userSchema.virtual("fullName").get(function() {
  return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}`;
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The last line exports `mongoose.model`

Anyway

```
User.create({name: { first: "John" ,last : "Walker"}, email: "jwlaker@aol.com", password : "piha111"}).
... then(user => firstUser = user).
... catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

leads to this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: User.create is not a function
```

Althouglh Node repl,sees User as a Function

```
<pre>&gt; User
<font color="#555753">{ [Function: require] resolve: { [Function: resolve] paths: [Function: paths] }, main: undefined, extensions: [Object: null prototype] { &apos;.js&apos;: [Function (anonymous)], &apos;.json&apos;: [Function (anonymous)],</font></pre> 

> typeof(User)
'function'
```

Comment: How are you importing User model/schema?

Comment: const User = require
("./models/user")

Comment: can you try const `mongoose = require("mongoose");`
`const Schema = mongoose.Schema;` and then `const UserSchema = new Schema()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using REPL

The following will get evaluated as 2 separate statements

```js
const User = require
("./models/user")
```

This will assign the function `require` to variable `User` and just evaluate the string "./models/user"

What you supposed to do is calling `require('./models.user')` and assign it to the `User` variable. It should be like this

```
const User = require('./models/user')
```

Note that this behaviour will not occur if you put the same code in a javascript file and execute it. Because the whole file will be parsed at the same time, not line by line like in REPL

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
User.create({name: { first: "John" ,last : "Walker"}, email: "jwlaker@aol.com", password : "piha111"}).
... then(user => firstUser = user).
... catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

try this one

```
let newUser =new User({name: { first: "John" ,last : "Walker"}, email: "jwlaker@aol.com", password : "piha111"});
newUser.save((err,usr)=>{ 
                    if(err) 
                        return err; 
                    firstUser = usr })
```